# Alternate fancy page header? left page = page number + chapter, right page = page number + section?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I currently use fancyhdr to display the chapter name and page number on each page. However, I would like to change this so that it displays the chapter on the left page and section on the right. I know how to do this manually, but it will take a long time. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Also, I would like the option to be able to add and change a horizontal line at the bottom of the page. I guess 0.5 textwidth would be good but I may want to change this later. Also, I don't want the font to all be in capitals and I don't want to include 'CHAPTER N:' at the top. It would also be nice to remove the page number from the top.

So on left page: name of chapter with line underneath at textwidth, then on the right page, the section name. I would like both of these headers on the inner part of the page. Then, at the bottom I would like a horizontal line with the page number underneath in the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new and modern package `scrlayer-scrpage` gives you all
you need. Of course, you can use `fancyhdr` for your document as
well. 
The length of the rules can be changed pretty easily using
`scrlayer-scrpage` but need much more effort with `fancyhdr` as
the default width is synchronized with the `headwidth`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,
footsepline,plainfootsepline,
headsepline]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,clines,markcase=nouppercase]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\KOMAoption{footsepline}{:.5\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Using `fancyhdr`

```
\documentclass[twoside,draft]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newlength{\footrulelength}
\setlength{\footrulelength}{.5\textwidth}

\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\def\footrule{
    \if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth%
    \fi%
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth%
    \null\hfill%
    \rule{\footrulelength}{\footrulewidth}\hfill\null%
    \vskip\footruleskip%
}
\makeatother
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{\rmfamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\rmfamily\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, worked brilliantly! however, how could I remove the 'Chapter 1:' part of the heading? and also I have realised, it looks nice to keep the page number at the bottom of the page, rather than using fancyhdr. How can I remove the page number?

Comment: Also, how could I shorten the length of the footrulewidth? I have tried using width=0.5/textwidth but I can't get it to work..

Comment: Which solution do you want to use? It will be easier using `scrlayer-scrpage` and even more easy using the corresponding KOMA-class. Changing the length of the `footrulewidth` (width a half of the textwidth seems to be unreasonable) involves hacking the `fancyhdr` internals

Comment: I tried to use scrlayer-scrpage but it could not define a lot of things and returned 4 errors, hence why I used fancyhdr

Comment: Telling me what the error was would be helpful ;-) Also, what do you want to define?

Comment: Package scrlayer error: cannot define '\cfoot', '\chead', '\renewpagestyle', '\newpagestyle', and then refers to the scrlayer document

Comment: For the mwe i posted? In a former comment you posted `width=0.5/textwidth` which is wrong.

Comment: You need to comment out package fancyhdr. They are not compatible.

Comment: fancyhdr commented out, reduced to 2 errors from 4, still cannot define newpagestyle and renewpagestyle

Comment: Your question never stated those commands. Please edit the question so that the answer suits it more properly. And please make sure to explain the issue with more than just keywords.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I'm not sure what commands you are referring too..fancyhdr commands? I was already using fancyhdr but manually inputted the text I wanted for each page..

Comment: There is no need to define `pagestyles`. The KOMA-script documentation states that this the experience interface. But i can't show you an example without knowing what you want to do.

Comment: I don't even know how the line in the foot is supposed to look  like, i am just guessing here.

Comment: the only commands where I use pagestyle are to remove the page number using '\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage'. Apart from this, I am not using it. Latex complains that the package scrlayer cannot define newpagestyle and renewpagestyle.

Comment: As to what I would like, the option to be able to change the horizontal line at the bottom of the page would be nice, I guess 0.5 textwidth but I may want to change this later. Also, I don't want the font to all be in capitals and to include 'CHAPTER N:' at the top, and also I want to remove the page number from the top left corner (when using Fancyhdr).

Comment: So on left page: name of chapter with line underneath at textwidth, then on right page section name. I would like both of these headers on the inner part of the page. Then, at the bottom I would like a horizontal line with the page number underneath in the center. Sorry for not being too clear before and thanks for your help!

Comment: Michael, can you *please* edit this into your question? Almost all of the stuff you are asking for is in the answer using scrlayer-scrpage. Please test the minimal example by copy/pasting, saving and compiling. The commentary system is not to sort out difficult problems.

Comment: I have copied the minimal example into my document and it produces said errors

Comment: This package has an affect on 'sideways figure' too, where sideways figures on the left page face the left and face right on the right page. Any ideas how to change this?

Comment: negative, this is the standard behaviour.